# how to pause the execution on failures in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

How to pause the script execution on failures and continue the executions, after performing some operations in Robot framework?

please suggest me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Pause Execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html#Pause%20Execution) keyword from the [Dialogs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html) library, which will open a dialog and pause robot until the dialog is dismissed.

Unfortunately, robot has no way of automatically running a keyword on any failure. You'll have to manage that yourself. For example, you could use [Run Keyword If Test Failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Failed) in a test teardown. Of course, you won't be able to continue that particular test, but it will let you pause before the next test.

If you need to allow the current test to continue after a failed keyword there are many keywords that can help you, such as [Run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) and all of the other `Run keyword if...` and `Run keyword unless...` keywords.